# Sort PHP array by inner value

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the below array that has been generated from wordpress using get_children().  The problem is that it can't seem to order the output by the menu order used in wordpress.

So the bellow array needs sorting by the inner value of the key [menu_order].  I've tried a number of different ways using usort etc, but can't seem to get it to work.

```
Array
(
[40] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 40
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2016-09-03 19:31:25
        [post_date_gmt] => 2016-09-03 19:31:25
        [post_content] => test 2
        [post_title] => Test 2
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => test-2
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2016-09-03 19:56:04
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-09-03 19:56:04
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 2
        [guid] => http://example.com/2
        [menu_order] => 2
        [post_type] => page
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )

[38] => WP_Post Object
    (
        [ID] => 38
        [post_author] => 1
        [post_date] => 2016-09-03 19:23:18
        [post_date_gmt] => 2016-09-03 19:23:18
        [post_content] => test 1
        [post_title] => Test 1
        [post_excerpt] => 
        [post_status] => publish
        [comment_status] => closed
        [ping_status] => closed
        [post_password] => 
        [post_name] => test-1
        [to_ping] => 
        [pinged] => 
        [post_modified] => 2016-09-03 19:51:17
        [post_modified_gmt] => 2016-09-03 19:51:17
        [post_content_filtered] => 
        [post_parent] => 2
        [guid] => http://example.com/1
        [menu_order] => 1
        [post_type] => page
        [post_mime_type] => 
        [comment_count] => 0
        [filter] => raw
    )
)
```

Comment: Use `usort` and provide a custom function (preferably a closure) which compares the element.

Answer (score 1):

Although you could use `usort` with a callback, the right solution would be to request items directly ordered via `get_children()`. You can achieve this by using the `orderby` argument. Like this:

```
$children = get_children(array(
  // other args here
  'orderby' => 'menu_order'
));
```

See WordPress' [get_children()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) and [get_posts()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) for more details.

Comment: I'd like to point out that you cannot use 'orderby' with get_children()

Comment: @David Cassidy: Since `get_children()` implementation actually forwards its arguments to `get_posts()`, it supports all arguments supported by `get_posts()`. See [get_children() implementation](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L345).
The documentation of `get_children()` also says _"Note: See get_posts() for a full list of $args parameters."_

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical usecase for [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
usort($array, function($a, $b){
    return $a['menu_order'] > $b['menu_order'];
});
```

Comment: You are supposed to return `0`, `1` or `-1`.

Comment: Works either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use usort: http://php.net/usort .  I tried to make it more details as below.

```
function menu_order($a, $b)
 {
    return strcmp($a->menu_order, $b->menu_order);
 }

usort($newsortedarray, "menu_order");

foreach ($newsortedarray as $array){

  // continue....

 }
```

Comment: Pretty sure strcmp will sort 1, 11, 2, instead of 1, 2, 11

Comment: This worked a treat.  What would be better to use instead of strcmp?

Comment: @DavidCassidy you can also try strcasecmp — Binary safe case-insensitive string comparison if you want to make case insensitive.  For more:http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php  Here is nice explanation for both of those funcrions: http://www.hackingwithphp.com/4/7/15/comparing-strings